# Runtime Error 1004: Method range Of Object _global Failed only for one user

Tags: excel, vba

I know there is a lot questions about run-time error, but I didn't find answer for my problem.
I have shared file between few people. Everybody can use this file, but ONLY one has a runtime error 1004 method range of object_global file; I checked windows settings (language and region) and we all have the same.

Line with problem:

```
pathfile = Range("pathfile") & "\" & Right(year, 2) & Format(period, "00") & "AC_" & entitny
```

Full Code:

```
Sub attachCommonVariables()
validated = False
period = Range("period_choose").Value
Year= Range("year_choose").Value
Entity= Range("Entity_choose").Value
pathfile = Range("pathfile") & "\" & Right(year, 2) & Format(period, "00") & "AC_" & entitny
If okres < 1 Or okres > 12 Then MsgBox "Wrong period":   Exit Sub
If rok < 2007 And rok > 2020 Then MsgBox "Wrong Year": Exit Sub
validated = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify what workbook/worksheet each `Range` is in/on.

Comment: We cannot see variable declarations, it is good practice to always declare variable (Use Option Explicit to enforce this). BTW, Year is a vba function, it is not a good idea to overload function names with variables names.

Comment: You have a typo at `entitny`

Comment: @VincentG Variable declarations are named ranges in worksheet and path file is a folder on company network \\en.group.xxx\Finance\Controlling\AC\2020\SAP Conso

Comment: @Rafae Variable declarations are things like `Dim validated as Boolean`, not named ranges (witch are the initialization values). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Comment: @VincentG
Ok, i know what you mean. Sorry, I misunderstood; And for this code, i dont have any Variable declarations.